# Lacie rikiki (500GB) Time Machine

Tags: time-machine, backup

I have a Lacie rikiki (500GB) harddrive that runs on Time Machine, and have been backing up for a couple of years. It now says it is full, and that it will delete old backups in order to make space to backup my current computer data. Does this mean that I am possibly losing important files (from two years ago) that I will therefore never again have access to? How does Time Machine decide what to delete?

Answer (score 1):

It deletes the oldest backups, as well as deleting all old backups each day, to make one backup each day. Unless you don't want to backup any more, older backups must be deleted. If you really have important files, why are they just on the Time Machine drive?

Comment: That is where my ignorance lay. I assumed that Time Machine was the equivalent to a hard drive and never got the message as to how it actually worked, but now I'm clear.

If my Time Machine (500GB) says that it doesn't have enough space to backup, does this mean that I currently have more than 500GB on my computer (internal hard drive)?

Comment: @Space3 it might. How big is your internal HD?

Comment: I don't know how/where to find that.

Comment: @Space3 Apple logo in the top, About This Mac, Storage....

Comment: Thank you. I have 500GB total storage on my computer, and it isn't yet full. My Time Machine should therefore be able to back everything up, but isn't doing so. Can you suggest why this may be? Shouldn't it delete old backups to make space for a new one, thereby always having a capacity of backing up a maximum of 500GB? Or do previous backups somehow also take up space?

Comment: @Space3 Time Machine makes incremental backups... That's why it says it's full, each day gets a backup of all changed files. So let it delete the oldest backups and let it run. It's designed to have minimal user interaction.

Comment: It deleted all backups except for the last one, and would say that it didn't have enough space to backup. I have now deleted ALL backups on my external hard drive, and am STILL getting the same message. I don't understand why.
Here's the message it gives me:
This backup is too large for the backup disk. The backup requires 445.63 GB but only 117.08 GB are available.

Time Machine needs work space on the backup disk, in addition to the space required to store backups. Open Time Machine preferences to select a larger backup disk or make the backup smaller by excluding files.

Comment: @Space3 it may be easier just to erase your backup drive and start over. However, maybe you should see why your startup disk is almost full. Download [OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more) to see what's taking up so much space.

Comment: OmniDiskSweeper tells me that I have 356.4GB used on my hard drive (external), but then when I 'sweep' it, it only shows me 88.2GB worth of files. Do you know what could be taking up the rest of the space? This seems to me to be a OmniDiscSweeper incoherence, unless you can enlighten me on how/what it actually does.

Comment: @Space3 some files aren't available to it, only to the root user. Have you clean out your trash, old files, etc? Try that and see if you can back up to your TM Drive.